# neo4j update old graph.db not cleanly shutdown

Tags: neo4j

I am receiving a "not cleanly shutdown" log message when attempting to open a 2 year old Neo4j database posted on github at https://github.com/IGS/disease-ontology/tree/master/database/neo4j. How do I open/update this database?

Here's how I got it initialized: Downloaded the graph_db.tgz to my local win7-64 machine (neo4j-community-1.9.RC2), extracted the graph.db file to the data subfolder, renamed it graph_ontology.db, and edited the server config file to point to it as follows:

> org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph_ontology.db

When starting Neo4j, the last entry in the log file is:

> 2013-05-21 17:23:33.418+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Startup failed: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@1f91d41b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@b86527e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: Mismatching store version found (Uknown while expecting v0.A.0) and the store is not cleanly shutdown. Recover the database with the previous database version and then attempt to upgrade

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the messages.log of the database to determine which neo4j version it was started with last.

In this case it is 1.4

You can get it from here: http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-1.4.2-windows.zip

You can easily just point the neo4j-shell to it:

1. create an upgrade.properties that contains: `allow_store_upgrade=true`
2. and then use: `bin/neo4j-shell -path graph_ontology.db -config upgrade.properties`

Here is the converted db for 1.9.GA: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14493611/disease_ontology_graphdb-1.9.tgz

Comment: Michael - Thank you for the direction and updating the graph.db. Works great!